# Inaccurate Count in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate a count of all records from several tables. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLEB B on A.A_KEY=B.B_KEY
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLEC C on A.A_KEY=C.C_KEY
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLED D on A.A_KEY=D.D_KEY
```

My results bring back records, and when I right click and choose "Count Rows", I get a number in the pop up box - let's say 100,000.

But when I do "Ctrl + A" to highlight all records, I get a different number of results - let's say 150,000. I right click and choose "Count Rows" again, and this time, the pop up NOW says 150,000 - where before I did "Ctrl + A", it said 100,000. If I export the data to a text file out of SQL Developer, I get 150,000 records.

If I query the same tables selecting a Count, I get 100,000 records.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DB.TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLEB B on A.A_KEY=B.B_KEY
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLEC C on A.A_KEY=C.C_KEY
    INNER JOIN DB.TABLED D on A.A_KEY=D.D_KEY
```

Has anyone seen this before? Is this something strange with my dataset, or something within SQL Developer that is a little "off"?

Answer (score 1):

doing a record count in a grid/resultset in SQL Developer doesn't actually count the rows in the current resultset being returned by the statement.

doing a record count runs another query that basically does a

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
  "your original query here"
     ) sub1
```

So, could it be different? yes.